# How to call multiple Knockout templates within one component

Tags: magento2, javascript, uicomponent, knockoutjs, requirejs

I'm currently experimenting with Knockout JS templates within Magento 2 and all is going well but I do have one thought.

It seems that you can only call `<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->` once per component as there is no option to create a second template and I can't see any components where Magento are using multiple templates.

Example code:

**My Template - `app/design/frontend/Ben/blankClone/Magento_Cms/templates/knockout.phtml`**

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "example-scope": {
                    "component": "Magento_Cms/js/knockout-example",
                    "exampleMessage": "<?= __('Hello Magento Stack Exchange!') ?>"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>

<div data-bind="scope: 'example-scope'">
    <h2 data-bind="text: message"></h2>
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

**My JS - It's a rough experiment ;) - `app/design/frontend/Ben/blankClone/Magento_Cms/web/js/knockout-example.js`**

```
define(['ko', 'jquery', 'uiComponent'], function(ko, $, Component) {
    'use strict';

    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

    var messageCollection = ['Hello', 'Hi', 'Yo!', 'Sup?'];

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            exampleMessage: 'This is the default title for my KO example',
            template: 'Magento_Cms/test'
        },

        initialize: function() {
            this._super();
        },

        /**
         * @return {exports.initObservable}
         * This is the same as var example = ko.observable('Example text');
         */
        initObservable: function () {
            this._super()
                .observe({
                    message: this.exampleMessage,
                    messageChanged: false,
                    updateTitle: false
                });

            return this;
        },

        updateTitle: function() {
            var numberOfMessages = messageCollection.length;
            var chosenMessageIndex = getRandomInt(0, (numberOfMessages - 1));
            var chosenMessage = messageCollection[chosenMessageIndex];

            this.message(chosenMessage);
            this.messageChanged(true);
        },

        resetTitle: function() {
            this.message(this.exampleMessage);
            this.messageChanged(false);
        },

        addYourOwnTitle: function() {

        }
    });
});
```

**My HTML templates**

**`app/design/frontend/Ben/blankClone/Magento_Cms/web/template/test.html`**

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores assumenda beatae blanditiis culpa cupiditate doloremque, expedita ipsum iure magni minima modi molestiae nulla optio porro ratione reiciendis repellat soluta voluptatum!`

**`app/design/frontend/Ben/blankClone/Magento_Cms/web/template/test-two.html`**

```
Hi!
```

**So my question is: Is it possible to call a second template? and if so, how?**

My thinking is you are limited to only one template per component to force you to write smaller components.

The only lead I have on this is the following markup, but I can't see how to get this working within Magento.

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'person-template'}"></div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to use as many template bindings as you want.  You could do this with a string identifier for the template URN

```
<!-- ko template: "Package_Namespace/template-name" --><!-- /ko -->
```

or a property on your view model that contains a template string.

```
<!-- ko template: someProp --><!-- /ko -->
```

You can also use the above with a `<script type="text/html"` named template, as per the [Knockout docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html)

If you're unfamiliar with how Knockout template URNs or `text/html` named templates work in Magento, I cover it OK in my [Magento 2: KnockoutJS Integration](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_knockoutjs_integration/) article.  I've also got a [comprehensive series on UI Components](http://alanstorm.com/series/magento-2-ui/) and [their underlying uiElement objects](http://alanstorm.com/series/magento-2-uielement-internals/) if you want to go really deep.